# Cannot open Ubuntu, stuck with intramfs

Tags: boot, upgrade, 14.04, wubi, initramfs

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10. I'm trying to upgrade to 14.04. After the upgrade Ubuntu is not opening up. I'm stuck with this black screen saying:

```
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target file system doesn't have /sbin/init
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg
```

BTW, my desktop is dual boot. I'm using Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10. I used Wubi. I'm using a different hard drive for the two OSs, so there's no problem with partitioning. How do I fix this? :(

I tried to update it twice. // uninstalled and reinstalled Wubi which gave me Ubuntu 12.10 which I was able to upgrade to 13.10. Now I want Ubuntu 14.04, but it always crashes. :(

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `/etc/default/grub` file

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_GRUB=" "
```

add `rootdelay=30 nomodeset` between quotes

then save the changes, exit and reboot.